# the best design for mapping enums to const classes

Tags: c++, dictionary, c++11, enums, constants

I have this example that works :
I create an object that implements "PartInterface" for each value of the enum and add them in a map. But I don't find this satisfactory, because everything could be inferred at compile time rather than at runtime.
Is there a more elegant way to do this in c++ 11?
Another solution would be to build the "YearPart", "MonthPart" and "DayPart" objects at each call of the "get" function,
but it seems to me less efficient...

```
#include <iostream>

#include <map>
#include <memory>

struct Date{
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
};

class PartInterface{
public:
    virtual const std::string & getName()const=0;
    virtual int getValue(const Date& d)const=0;
    virtual ~PartInterface(){}
};

class Part : public PartInterface{
public:
    Part(const std::string& name):_name(name){}

    const std::string & getName()const{
        return _name;
    }
    virtual int getValue(const Date& d)const=0;
    
private:
    std::string _name;
};

class YearPart : public Part{
public:
    YearPart():Part("year"){}
    int getValue(const Date& d)const{
        return d.year;
    }
};

class MonthPart : public Part{
public:
    MonthPart():Part("month"){}
    int getValue(const Date& d)const{
        return d.month;
    }
};

class DayPart : public Part{
public:
    DayPart():Part("day"){}
    int getValue(const Date& d)const{
        return d.day;
    }
};

enum DatePart{
    Year,
    Month,
    Day
};

class Parts{
public:
    Parts(){
        _map[Year].reset(new YearPart());
        _map[Month].reset(new MonthPart());
        _map[Day].reset(new DayPart());
    };
    
    const PartInterface& get(const DatePart& date_part)const{
        return * (_map.find(date_part)->second);
    }
    
private:
    std::map<DatePart, std::unique_ptr<PartInterface> > _map;
};

int main() {
  Date d({2016, 7, 23});
  const Parts parts;
  std::cout << "Date " 
    << parts.get(Year).getValue(d) << " " 
    << parts.get(Month).getValue(d) << " " 
    << parts.get(Day).getValue(d) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you building your own date library? That's just asking for trouble...

Comment: @Dai, this is just to create a meaningful example, but I often encounter this design problem.

Comment: tbh, the whole design is rather questionable, not only the runtime mapping from enum to instance of derived class. Why use derived classes in the first place? Why `getValue` isnt `static` or a free function?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number The idea would be to create getValue and getName functions that take the enum as parameter? Indeed, it seems to be a good solution, however I liked the idea of classes to group all the elements of the same "Part" together.

Comment: Why do you use `std::map::find`, if you don't test, if the result is there or not? If anyone passes `Day+1` in, any access to the function result yields undefined behaviour. Furthermore why use a `std::map` given it's overhead? The enum constants have integral values 0, 1 and 2, so why not just declare `_map` as `std::unique_ptr<PartInterface>[3]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest I don't understand why you need this whole machinery when a simple `int getPart(DatePart,Date)` would suffice. Most of the inefficiencies in the code seem to be selfmade. Anyhow, to adress only the mapping from enum to something else at compile time, you can use a template and specialize it for the enum values (I left out all the other stuff, because I dont understand it, but you can add it back, the solution applies the same):

```
#include <iostream>

struct Date{
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
};

enum DatePart{
    Year,
    Month,
    Day
};

template <DatePart DP>
int getPart(const Date&);

template <> int getPart<Year>(const Date& d){ return d.year;}
template <> int getPart<Month>(const Date& d){ return d.month;}
template <> int getPart<Day>(const Date& d){ return d.day;}

int main() {
  Date d({2016, 7, 23});
  std::cout << "Date " 
    << getPart<Year>(d) << " " 
    << getPart<Month>(d) << " " 
    << getPart<Day>(d) << std::endl;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/evTeKEzoo)

As mentioned above, if you really need the `Part` stuff, the solution applies as well. Instead of specializing a template to return different members based on the enum value you can specialize it to return different derived instances of some base class (it could even be different return types, you don't need runtime polymorphism when you want to choose the "part" at compile time anyhow).

Comment: I must confess that I did not know this way of taking an enum as a template parameter, thanks for this answer!

Comment: @JeromeDemantke eventually I realized what made me question your design. You are using runtime polymorphism (inheritance + virtual functions) but then ask how to select which function to call at compile time already. Runtime polymorphism comes at a cost, but more importantly its a feature you should use when you need it, and not use it when you want something else